# How to enable systemd's service without waiting?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, networkmanager, services

I'm trying to make fastest boot possible and did run `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @5.800s
└─multi-user.target @5.800s
  └─NetworkManager.service @4.201s +1.598s
    └─basic.target @4.201s
      └─sockets.target @4.196s
        └─dbus.socket @4.196s
          └─sysinit.target @4.196s
            └─systemd-update-utmp.service @4.108s +87ms
              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @4.066s +41ms
                └─local-fs.target @4.066s
                  └─boot-efi.mount @3.964s +101ms
                    └─boot.mount @3.932s +26ms
                      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9846843d\x2d8ec1\x2d4574\x2d8bcc\x2d4790440cad5f.service @3.714s +218ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9846843d\x2d8ec1\x2d4574\x2d8bcc\x2d4790440cad5f.device @3.713s
```

As you can see `└─NetworkManager.service @4.201s +1.598s` adds `+1.598s` seconds to the boot time. However I don't need to have network running to type password and while I'm typing username/password on personal PC, network has enough time to connect.

So I tried:
`rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service`

However, that disabled NM completly at boot time and enabling it with `systemctl enable NetworkManager` is just creation of same symlink:

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.
```

**Is there any way to start `NetworkManager.service` during boot, but not as dependency of `multi-user.target` ??**

Comment: `systemd-analyze critical-chain` has an optional parameter -- name of the unit for which the chain is built. I think that it will be more useful to get a critical chain of the unit which is responsible for your UI (e. g. `gdm.service` or whatever you are using).

Comment: @intelfx `multi-user.target` does not start a dm.  It's boot to console, part of my point about switching VTs mid boot.

Comment: @goldilocks: the chain posted by Miro is up to `graphical.target`, so I assume he uses a graphical login.

Comment: @intelfx Whoops, missed that part (because I did not realize graphical-target built on multi-user, and the last line in the OP).  This is just silly then, IMO.  But I did get a oneshot service calling `chvt 2` and run `Before=dbus.socket` and `WantedBy=getty.target` to work together with an added `getty@tty2.service`.  Of course that's only useful sans graphical.target.

Comment: @intelfx Yes. You're right. `slim.service` doesn't depend on `NetworkManager.service`. I've misunderstood some things with systemd. I thought it means, `graphical.target` starts after `NetworkManager.service` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has little sense. "To start during boot" means precisely "to start as dependency of the default target".

Note that *systemd starts everything in parallel*, so the 1.5-second NetworkManager startup **does not delay anything** except services which explicitly wait for network (apparently, you have none; otherwise they would have been shown in the graph).

Comment: Not saying you are wrong (yet), but if the 1.6 second start-up does not delay anything, then why does `multi-user-target` not kick in until precisely 1.6 s after `NetworkManager`?  Pure coincidence?

Comment: @goldilocks: because `multi-user.target` is declared started only after all its dependencies complete their startup. However, the target itself does nothing: it exists merely to group other units. If no units depend on `multi-user.target` (which *is* the case -- nothing depends on the main target), then this delay does not really delay anything.

Comment: You are saying you can log in *before* `multi-user.target` has completed?

Comment: @goldilocks: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  All login requires is `getty.target` -- but by default that will only start `tty`, then it looks to be `systemd-logind.service`. I guess you could dig into the priorities of those so you could switch VT's during boot and log in...which seems pointless to save a second.  You do something to switch to tty2 automatically as soon as logind starts.

Comment: @goldilocks: If you want an explicitly started getty at some another tty, then you just do `systemctl enable getty@<whatever>.service` and it will be started unconditionally, not only after the VT in question is activated and logind catches that event.

Comment: How can this answer be correct? By definition of "critical chain", if something is listed as part of it, then at some point systemd is fingerdrumming waiting for that thing to finish starting up.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski There are different critical chains leading to different units. A critical chain to `default.target` doesn't really matter. On the other hand, a critical chain to the OP's display manager is unlikely to include NetworkManager.